# Time-scale calculus (an similar approaches - measure chains) on more general "time" sets

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, differential-calculus, difference-equations, discrete-dynamical-systems

Time-scale calculus [0], also called calculus on measure chains (introduced in this widely cited article [1] and also here [2]) unified the concept of derivative of a functions $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and forward difference operator of a sequence. This generalization allows one to formulate in very nice, unified way important theorems from dynamical systems by formulating them on a single "time" set - instead of the usually way where they are formulated and are proved twice, once in discrete-time and once in the continuous-time case (see, e.g., [3] for such a generalized version of Hartman-Grobman).

Time-scale calculus works by replacing the usual "time" set, which is an open interval for functions and a subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ for sequences, by a more general set $\mathbb{T}$, which is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$, subject to a few axioms, which can actually be stated abstractly.

**Question 1:** Does anyone know why it is necessary to assume $\mathbb{T}$ to be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$? Probably some theorems would break down, if one merely states the axioms, but allows $\mathbb{T}$ to be any partially ordered set (and potentially being a topological space in addition)? Even though the author developing these approaches in [1,2]

**Question 2:** Do there exist any competing approaches to unify discrete-time and continous-time dynamical systems? Perhaps there are some nifty constructions from category theory that already present a very general, unified framework for difference operators and differentials?
(When talking about equations, apparently using the Laplace transform one can show that there is some link between a difference equation and a differential equation [4], though this approach does not seem sufficiently general to me.)

**Question 3:** My motivation to ask about this comes from probability theory,where random fields are a generalization of stochastic processes where the "time" set is not the usual ordered set, but can be, for example, a lattice.
While random fields are important models in physics (spin glasses), which pushes the development of this field so that we now have this nice general theory of which stochastic processes are a special case, I wonder, is there no impetus (other than a few, not really important examples mentioned in [1,2]) coming from applications that will push the development of time-scale calculus further, so that we can one day view the field of ODEs as a special case of a more general "ordinary time-scales equations" field?

[0] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-scale_calculus
[1] https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF03323153
[2] https://sci-hub.wf/10.1016/s0362-546x(96)00204-0
[3] https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-the-australian-mathematical-society/article/generalized-theorem-of-hartmangrobman-on-measure-chains/83CA0D1C155AAF315CB30C1F226506A3
[4] https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145523/links-between-difference-and-differential-equations