# What are the limits of what the theory of time-scale calculus can capture?

Tags: differential-calculus, difference-equations

Time-scale calculus [0], also called calculus on measure chains (introduced in this widely cited article [1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/431149/time-scale-calculus-an-similar-approaches-measure-chains-on-more-general-ti) and also here [2]) unified the concept of derivative of a functions $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and forward difference operator of a sequence. This then leads to a very nice, unified treatment of important theorems from dynamical systems, which usually are proved twice, once in a discrete and once in the continuous case (e.g. [3] for such a generalized version of Hartman-Grobman).

This works by replacing the "time" set, which is an open interval for functions and a subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ for sequences by a more general set $\mathbb{T}$, which is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$, subject to a few axioms, which can actually be stated abstractly.

**Question :** What theorems exist that completely "fall out" of this unifying framework? "Fall out" could mean various things. Most likely that they can be formulated abstractly but their proof would only be valid for a particular few concrete time sets, that correspond to the  classical discrete-time vs. continuous-time ones (e.g. $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$) and one would have to make a case distinction on which time set one has and write the proof out exactly like in the classical case - in which case there would be no real reason to bother to formulate them abstractly and could just stick to the standard definition.

(A different question on time-scale calculus is my [other question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/431149/time-scale-calculus-an-similar-approaches-measure-chains-on-more-general-ti). From the references listed there it seems that most of the basic, undergraduate theorems can be generalized to time-scale calculus, but I could not find a really compelling theorem that cannot readily be generalized. Furthermore, in the book "Dynamic equations on time scales" by Bohner and Peterson, the authirs say in the introduction that "many results concerning differential equations carry over quite easily to corresponding results for difference equations, while other results seem to be completely different in nature from their continuous counterparts", but do not state which ones  - and I found it after a while of browsing to be too time consuming to find a really nice examples where the theory of time-scale calculus comes crashing down. If I would not more about dynamical systems I guess I would know better where to look at. Conversely, there is the book "Discrete Calculus by Analogy" F.A. Izadi et al that does not use time-scale calculus, but develops discrete calculus in complete analogy to the classical continuous version, including ordinary differential equations, which additionally shows that probably quite a number of results must be generalizable to time-scale calculus.)